# PHP rtrim function

Tags: php, string, function

```
$foo  = 'abvgd';

// "s" in the end
$foos = 'abvgs';
$bar  = 'any_string';

$foo_concat  = $foo  . $bar;
$foos_concat = $foos . $bar;

$foo_decode  = rtrim($foo_concat,  $bar);
$foos_decode = rtrim($foos_concat, $bar);

echo "\n$foo  \t $foo_concat  \t $foo_decode";
echo "\n$foos \t $foos_concat \t $foos_decode";
// $foo  == $foo_decode
// $foos != $foos_decode
```

Result:

abvgd    abvgdany_string         abvgd

abvgs    abvgsany_string         abv

Where's the "s"?)

Comment: second parameter: `You can also specify the characters you want to strip, by means of the charlist parameter. Simply list all characters that you want to be stripped. With .. you can specify a range of characters. 
`

Answer (score 5):

[`rtrim()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php) cuts off the **characters** in the second parameter.

That means it cuts off `a`, `n`, `y`, `_`, `s`, `t`, `r`, `i`, `n` and `g` individually until none of these are present at the end of the string.

If you want to mimic **your** behaviour, you can do it the following way:

```
<?php
    $totalString = 'this is my string of any_string any_stringany_string';
    $stringToCutOff = 'any_string';

    var_dump(rtrim_string($totalString, $stringToCutOff));
    // string(32) "this is my string of any_string "

    function rtrim_string($string, $stringToCutOff) {
        $stringToCutOffLength = strlen($stringToCutOff);
        while (substr($string, -$stringToCutOffLength) == $stringToCutOff) {
            $string = substr($string, 0, -$stringToCutOffLength);
        }
        return $string;
    }
?>
```

[**CODEPAD DEMO**](http://codepad.org/rDW2iOAZ)

Answer (score 2):

The second parameter is a list of all characters to be removed, "any_string" contains `g` and `s`, so both of those characters were removed from the end of the string.

If you want to remove a whole string from the end of another you could use:

```
$str = preg_replace('#'.preg_quote($toRemove,'#').'$#','',$str);
```

Or if you're aiming to remove all repetitions of a certain string from the end:

```
$str = preg_replace('#('.preg_quote($toRemove,'#').')+$#','',$str);
```

(and the above with optional spaces between occurrences):

```
$str = preg_replace('#(\s*'.preg_quote($toRemove,'#').'\s*)+$#','',$str);
```

Comment: Technically the regex would only match one instance of the string. Add parenthesis and a `+` before the `$`.

Comment: @h2ooooooo Well yes that was the point, if he's appending "any_string" and then testing removing "any_string" from the end, it seems as though replacing 1 instance is the goal.

Comment: Yet he was using `rtrim`, which will keep on removing until nothing is present (eg `/([any_string]+)$/`)

Comment: @h2ooooooo Yes, but he clearly doesn't know how `rtrim` works or this question wouldn't be here. I'll add an alternative as we cannot be sure what the goal is.

Answer (score 1):

`rtrim()` removes character from the right side, that matches the second parameter, in your case its variable `$bar`.

It takes second parameter (`$bar`) as charlist, so it takes all the letters individually. In your case, `$foos_concat = $foos.$bar; // "abvgsany_string"`.

So its removing `"gs"` from `"abvgsany_string"`, as `g` & `s` is in charlist of any_string (`$bar`).

Had `$foos_concat` been "`abvgspany_string"` with `"p"` in it, it would have given you `"abvgsp"` as its rtrim() and `"p"` is not in the second parameter (`$bar`) charlist.